# using angular $http get with asp net web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to use an asp web api to populate an html table using angular. everything works great if I debug in firefox (I'm assuming because my web service is being returned in json) however in ie and chrome it does not load (the web service returns xml in these browsers).  In the webapiconfig I attempted to always make the service return json by adding.

```
    Dim appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(Function(t) t.MediaType = "application/xml")
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType)
```

this appears to work when I navigate to the api in all browsers it is returning json however the $http get is still now working in chrome and ie.

in ie I get the following error

```
    Unhandled exception at line 21, column 406 in http://localhost:53175/Scripts/angular.min.js

    0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$injector:nomod] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/nomod?p0=api%2Fproducts
```

here is my get

```
    angular.module("api/products").constant("dataUrl", "sportstore.json").controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $resource, dataUrl) {
    $scope.data = {};

    var resultPromise = $resource(dataUrl);
    resultPromise.success(function (data) {
        $scope.data.products = data;
    })


    });
```

any thoughts?

additional info

here is my api controller

```
<pre>
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web.Http
Imports apitoform.productRepository

Namespace Controllers
    Public Class productController
        Inherits ApiController

    Private repo As productRepository = productRepository.Current

    Public Function GetAllProducts() As IEnumerable(Of product)
        Return repo.GetAll()
    End Function

    End Class
    End Namespace
</pre>
```

and here is the j_son that is being returned ( I am working through the  pro Angular book if it looks familiar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular.module with 1 parameter returns the module with that name - you need to define your module with a list of dependent modules (or empty array if none) like the following:

```
angular.module("api/products", [])...
```

The error referenced gives an error with details on the problem (angular's very good about their error messages): https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=api%2Fproducts

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is c# code, but it should illustrate the basic idea for returning Json only from web api. It's actual code from one of my projects.

```
 [Route("api/users/getbyemail/")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetByEmail(string email)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _userService.GetByEmail(email);

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "value");
            response.Content = new ObjectContent(typeof(IEnumerable<UserViewModel>), result ?? new List<UserViewModel>(), new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            return response;
        }
    }
```

So you are returning HttpResponseMessage with Json content.

I'm also doing similar in a scenario where I just need to return the data from one of the MVC controllers and that is even easier:

```
public ActionResult Get(string guid)
        {
            var profileVm = _profileService.Get(guid);
            if (profileVm != null)
            {
                return Json(profileVm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }

            return new HttpNotFoundResult();
        }
```